# MS Access: Sum of closest N values of particular type of records

Tags: sql, ms-access-2010

The task is the following:
I have records of trades made, they are characterized by number, time of trade, product and volume. For every trade I need to see time, product, volume, and **the sum of volumes of last N trades (made before this trade) of the product of this trade**. The query need to be done MS Access. The data looks like this:

```
Number  |  Time | Product  |  Volume
1       |  10   | A        |  20
2       |  11   | B        |  20
3       |  12   | B        |  25
4       |  13   | A        |  20
5       |  14   | A        |  40
6       |  15   | B        |  20
7       |  16   | C        |  70
8       |  17   | A        |  20
9       |  18   | B        |  60
10      |  19   | B        |  10
```

Expected result for trades 8 and 9, Top 2 (N=2):

```
 Number  |  Time | Product  |  Volume  | Sum
   8     |  17   | A        |  20      |  60
   9     |  18   | B        |  20      |  45
```

Comment: Number and time are reserved words, so in order to make that MS Access query to run, you have to enclose those field names into [], e.g. [time], [number]

Comment: How are you getting 60 and 45? Before Time 17 and 18, `A = 20 + 20 + 40 = 80` and `B = 20 + 25 + 20 = 65`

Comment: The number is unique, it is a code for trade (also ascending with time). 60 and 45 come fron the fact that sum is only for top 2.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done in MS Access by selecting the right rows and then aggregating:

```
select max(t.number) as number, max(t.time) as time, t.product,
       sum(volume)
from trades t
where t.time in (select top 5 t2.time
                 from trades as t2
                 where t2.product = t.product
                 order by t2.time desc
                );
group by t.product;
```

Comment: The probleme is that I need these results for every trade, not only last one (for first trade sum will be 0)